# How to measure speed of incrementing of a variable?

Tags: android

I've been developing an app for a project of mine which includes a module where I track the steps of the user using an accelerometer.
As of now, I currently can only track the number of steps that the user walks but not the speed. I did some research but I couldn't find much.

The code that I'm using for the pedometer module in the app is from this:
https://github.com/google/simple-pedometer

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want GPS coordinates. Two points at a set interval of time will give you distance traveled in X amount of seconds, which gives you the speed.

Comment: for accelerometer approach look up "inertial navigation system". Otherwise use gps/location along with timestamps to calculate speed ( which will most likely vary from one calc to the next - so you'll be calculating averages somewhere )

Comment: every time user makes a step record time of step, and check how much time passed from previous step. Then you can calculate speed like if time between steps is 1.041 sec, then speed is 1/1.041 steps per second

Comment: For estimates you could store step distance and use that with Vlads approach to get ground speed.

Comment: Thanks guys, for the quick responses! I understand that using accelerometer for this kind of function increases error, but I use this in quite some other functions like number of push-ups, number of sit-ups etc. ( You get the general idea.) So even though I am using this code, I modified its parameters for different such activities (A set of parameters for each activity that the user does like a set of sit-ups or a set of push-ups) so even though I integrate GPS based speed calculation, I doesn't fully help cause then it would be only effective when running.

Comment: So what I really need is what I asked above.

Comment: I understand that I didn't ask it the right way so that you guys would understand that I needed to use it for other than just walking. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Accelerometer with gyroscope won't work here because of dead reckoning - drastically increasing error caused by integrating original error. You should calculate speed by taking GPS coordinates, taken with some equal time intervals. I used that here: https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights/tree/ReadingSensors/app/src/main/java/alex_shutov/com/ledlights/sensor/gps

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm definitely going to use it. However, if you can see the comment I've posted on my original question, this would only be effective when the user is running. So I'd really like to know how to accomplish this with the code I'm using (using the accelerometer), even though I understand that this can introduce errors.